# Point sprite alpha blending issue (Android / OpenGL ES 2.0)

Tags: android, opengl-es, blending, point-sprites

I've recently started looking into OpenGL ES for Android and am working on a drawing app. I've implemented some basics such as point sprites, path smoothing and FBO for double buffering. At the moment I am playing around with the glBlendFunc, more specifically when I put two textures close to each other with the same color/alpha values, the alpha gets added so it appears darker at the intersection of the sprites. This is a problem because the stroke opacity is not preserved if a lot of points are close together, as the color tends to more opaque rather than staying with the same opacity. Is there a way to make the textures have the same color on the intersection, i.e. have the same alpha value for the intersecting pixels, but keep the alpha values for the rest of the pixels?

Here's how I've done the relevant parts of the app:

- for drawing the list of point sprites I use blending like this:

  ```
  GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
  GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  ```
- the app uses an FBO with a texture, where it renders each brush stroke first and then this texture is rendered to the main screen. The blending func there is:

  ```
  GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
  GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  ```
- OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't support alpha masking;
- there is no DEPTH_TEST function used anywhere in the app;
- the textures for the point sprites are PNGs with transparent backgrounds;
- the app supports texture masking which means one texture is used for the shape and one texture is used for the content;
- my fragment shader looks like this:

  ```
  precision mediump float;

  uniform sampler2D uShapeTexture;
  uniform sampler2D uFillTexture;
  uniform float vFillScale;

  varying vec4 vColor;
  varying float vShapeRotation;
  varying float vFillRotation;
  varying vec4 vFillPosition;

  vec2 calculateRotation(float rotationValue) {
      float mid = 0.5;
      return vec2(cos(rotationValue) * (gl_PointCoord.x - mid) + sin(rotationValue) * (gl_PointCoord.y - mid) + mid,
              cos(rotationValue) * (gl_PointCoord.y - mid) - sin(rotationValue) * (gl_PointCoord.x - mid) + mid);
  }

  void main() {
      // Calculations.
      vec2 rotatedShape = calculateRotation(vShapeRotation);
      vec2 rotatedFill = calculateRotation(vFillRotation);
      vec2 scaleVector = vec2(vFillScale, vFillScale);
      vec2 positionVector = vec2(vFillPosition[0], vFillPosition[1]);

      // Obtain colors.
      vec4 colorShape = texture2D(uShapeTexture, rotatedShape);
      vec4 colorFill = texture2D(uFillTexture, (rotatedFill * scaleVector) + positionVector);

      gl_FragColor = colorShape * colorFill * vColor;
  }
  ```
- my vertex shader is this:

  ```
  attribute vec4 aPosition;
  attribute vec4 aColor;
  attribute vec4 aJitter;
  attribute float aShapeRotation;
  attribute float aFillRotation;
  attribute vec4 aFillPosition;
  attribute float aPointSize;

  varying vec4 vColor;
  varying float vShapeRotation;
  varying float vFillRotation;
  varying vec4 vFillPosition;

  uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;

  void main() {
      // Sey position and size.
      gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * (aPosition + aJitter);
      gl_PointSize = aPointSize;

      // Pass values to fragment shader.
      vColor = aColor;
      vShapeRotation = aShapeRotation;
      vFillRotation = aFillRotation;
      vFillPosition = aFillPosition;
  }
  ```

I've tried playing around with the glBlendFunc parameters but I can't find the right combination to draw what I want. I've attached some images showing what I would like to achieve and what I have at the moment. Any suggestions?

[image]

**The Solution**

Finally managed to get this working properly with a few lines thanks to @ Rabbid76. First of all I had to configure my depth test function before I draw to the FBO:

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LESS);

// Drawing code for FBO.

GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Then in my fragment shader I had to make sure that any pixels with alpha < 1 in the mask are discarded like this:

```
...
vec4 colorMask = texture2D(uMaskTexture, gl_PointCoord);
if (colorMask.a < 1.0)
    discard;
else
    gl_FragColor = calculatedColor;
```

And the result is (flickering is due to Android emulator and gif capture tool):

[image]

Comment: If you discard any pixels where alpha is less than 1, wouldn't all your pixels get discarded in your example, as all pixerls have alpha components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the [glBlendFunc](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml)
with the functions `(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` and you use
[glBlendEquation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBlendEquation.xhtml) with the equation `GL_FUNC_ADD` then the destination color is 
calculated as follows:

```
C_dest = C_src * A_src + C_dest * (1-A_src)
```

If you blend for example `C_dest = 1` with `C_src = 0.5` and `A_src = 0.5` then:

```
C_dest = 0.75 = 1 * 0.5 + 0.5 * 0.5
```

If you repeat blending the same color `C_src = 0.5` and `A_src = 0.5` then the destination color becomes *darker*:

```
C_dest = 0.625 = 0.75 * 0.5 + 0.5 * 0.5
```

Since the new target color is always a function of the original target color and the source color, the color can not remain equel when blending 2 times, because the target color has already changed after the 1st time blending (except `GL_ZERO`).

You have to avoid that any fragment is blended twice. If all fragments are drawn to the same depth (2D) then you can use the depth test for this:

```
glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
glDepthFunc( GL_LESS );

// do the drawing with the color

glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
```

Or the stencil test can be used. For example, the stencil test can be set to pass only when the stencil buffer is equal to 0.
Every time a fragment is to be written the stencil buffer is incremented:

```
glClear( GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT );
glEnable( GL_STENCIL_TEST );
glStencilOp( GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_INCR );
glStencilFunc( GL_EQUAL, 0, 255 );

// do the drawing with the color

glDisable( GL_STENCIL_TEST );
```

#### Extension to the answer

Note that you can [discard](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Special_operations) fragments which should not be drawn.
If the fragment in your sprite texture has an alpha channel of 0 you should discard it.

Note, if you discard a fragment neither the color nor the depth and stencil buffer will be written.

> Fragment shaders also have access to the `discard` command. When executed, this command causes the fragment's output values to be discarded. Thus, the fragment does not proceed on to the next pipeline stages, and any fragment shader outputs are lost.

*Fragment shader*

```
if ( color.a < 1.0/255.0 )
    discard;
```

Comment: Hi Rabbid76. This is a good direction I think. However since the sprites are pngs i have to draw their transparent pixels once at least so with this approach the alpha pixels are kept and not replaced by non alpha pixels from the next sprite. Any ideas hiw to tackle that?

Comment: In that case the pixels of the next sprite would not be rendered though, right? Because if the alpha pixels of the previous sprite are rendered already the stencil values there will already be 1, so if a colored pixel is to be at that location (coming from the next sprite) it will fail the stencil test. Sorry, I'm trying to ubderstand it :) I should mention that i could be rendering a few sprites during the same render cycle, not only one.

Comment: okay I think it will be easier with an example. Lets say we have two PNG brush shape sprites which overlap and I have to render at the same time. When the first one gets written to the stencil buffer, all pixels, including the transparent alpha ones, will be 1, right? So when the second sprite is written, the pixels that would cover some of the transparent pixels from the first sprite will fail the stencil test because the alpha pixels are already there, which means that I will have part of the second sprite missing. Did I explain better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150531/discussion-between-georgi-and-rabbid76).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this using the fixed-function blending in OpenGL ES 2.0, because what you want isn't actually alpha blending. What you want is a logical operation (e.g. max(src, dst)) which is rather different to how OpenGL ES blending works.

If you want to do path / stroke / fill rendering with pixel-exact edges you might get somewhere with using stencil masks and stencil tests, but you can't do transparency in this case - just boolean operators.